# Which is the major product formed on nitration of benzyl methyl ether?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, regioselectivity

Which is the major and minor product formed from the reaction of benzyl methyl ether with dinitrogen pentoxide?

[image: Nitration of benzyl methyl ether]

I know that $\ce{NO2+}$ is behaving as an electrophile here and attacking the aromatic ring. Furthermore, the substituent directs electrophilic substitution to the *ortho*- and *para*-positions. I thought that since the *ortho* position is more sterically hindered, the *para* product should be the major product and the *ortho*  product minor.

However, the answer I was given says the opposite, i.e. that the  *ortho* product is major and the *para* product is minor. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: The *ortho* position isn't that hindered and there are two *ortho* positions compared to only one *para* so this probably accounts for the observed products.

Comment: This isn't a literature reaction, and in general nitrations using N2O5 are not common. There is only one paper which mentions any kind of nitration of benzyl methyl ether, and the authors note that with a similar compound (PhCH2CH2OMe) the regioselectivity of nitration depends on the choice of reagent: https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/jo9606867.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 1) $\ce{NO+2}$ electrophile.

Yes

> 2) Benzene ring is attached to an activating group, so meta positions
>   are enriched and electrophile has chances of attacking ortho/para
>   positions.

The effect of the substituent in your example is probably similar to the effect of a methyl group (*e.g.* replacing a methyl hydrogen with a methoxy group won't have a big effect on the electron donating ability of the substituent).  Look at the relative rates of nitration in the following figure.

[image]

([image source](http://www2.chemistry.msu.edu/faculty/reusch/VirtTxtJml/benzrx1.htm))

We see that in toluene the *ortho* and *para* positions react 43 and 55 times (these two numbers are rather close) faster than in benzene, while reaction rate at the *meta* position changes little from benzene.  This is consistent with the pi-donating ability of a methyl group adding electron density to the *ortho* and *para* positions making them more attractive to attack by an electrophile.

> 3) *ortho* position is more sterically hindered, hence *para*- major
>   product and *ortho* minor product.

Look at the relative rate for the *ortho* position in *t*-butyl-benzene, here steric factors definitely play a role in slowing down attack at the *ortho* position. By comparison, the methyl group (and your substituent) is not very large and may slightly reduce the reaction rate at the *ortho* position in toluene (43 *vs.* 55 rather than both numbers being 55) or your example.

Another factor to consider is statistical in nature, there are two *ortho* positions, but only one *para* position. So, if everything else were equal, we would expect twice as much *ortho* product as *para* product.

In summary,

- the electron donating effect of the substituent increases the rate at the *ortho* and *para* positions to a similar degree
- steric factors might reduce the rate at the *ortho* position a small amount
- statistical factors favor twice as much attack at the *ortho* position compared to the *para* position

This statistical effect is the largest of the three and is consistent with the *ortho* isomer being the major product.

One final cautionary note. When we discuss reaction rates we are really discussing kinetics - which product will form the fastest. However, electrophilic aromatic substitution is an equilibrium process. If you allow the reaction to run at high temperature, or for a long time, then thermodynamics can take over and we may wind up with a product composition based on relative product stability rather than kinetic factors.

Comment: Is there any example of nitration reaction on substituted benzene where there is a clear majority of para substitution?

Comment: sure, *t*-butyl-benzene

Comment: If we take statistics, H-bonding would come into play right? Then if we take Intermolecular H-bonding > Intramolecular H-bonding.... ?

Comment: @SujithSizon How would H-bonding come into play here?

Comment: @ron intramolecular H-bonding between nitrogen attached oxygen(ortho case) and  hydrogen attached to the starting/ending methyl group?

Comment: No, there is no hydrogen bonding involving the methyl hydrogen.  In fact in the starting material or the two products, there is no hydrogen bonding.

Comment: @ron glad to have that cleared, thank you so much.

Comment: @SujithSizon Your welcome!